# How to set view as image background in android?

Tags: android

I am try to set image background . I am creating a View that's background color is red .

All view and set image background programmatically .

this is my code

```
    final View trans_View = new ImageView(MyClass.this);
    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                100, 100);
                        params.setMargins(10, 2, 10, 2);
                        trans_View.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        trans_View.setLayoutParams(params);
```

**img.setBackground   View ????**

example-
Actual image :
[image]

when i select Image then display below output.

[image]

I don't know how to set view as image background .

Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.

If you just need to add background to your `ImageView` use `setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)`.

Or if you're **really** need to use `View` as a background, you can use `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

However this is **not** recomended, since there will be unneccecary overdraw.